# What user-agent "BBBike" is?

Tags: nginx, web, user-agent

I've observed loads of robots.txt where a user-agent called "BBBike" is blocked. I'm curious what the story behind it is. Does anyone know? Or maybe it's just something happened in the, we continue doing it, but no idea why?

Googling BBBike lead me to loads of bike shops or maps, but I doubt they would randomly crawl websites. Or is it the case?

Examples:
https://www.who.int/robots.txt
https://www.mifotra.gov.rw/robots.txt

Comment: Your guess is likely as good as anyone's.

Comment: No idea why this was closed, as there is an answer to the question, which is not opinion-based.

Comment: my guess is https://www.bbbike.org/ , which finds bike routes for various cities around the world. Perhaps it crawls web sites for some of its street data? [their github](https://github.com/eserte/bbbike)